# How can I change my site URL with htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my url:

```
http://localhost/blog/post/?meta=How-We-Build-Your-Website
```

and I need it to be like this:

```
http://localhost/blog/How-We-Build-Your-Website
```

How can I do it with `.htaccess`?

Comment: `/blog/post/?meta=How-We-Build-Your-Website` - this is not the final endpoint - what is the "file" that actually handles the request? Is it perhaps `/blog/post/index.php`?

Comment: yes its index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To internally rewrite a request for the friendly URL `/blog/How-We-Build-Your-Website` to `/blog/post/index.php?meta=How-We-Build-Your-Website` (the underlying file that actually handles the request) you can do something like the following in `.htaccess` using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^blog/([^w-]+)$ blog/post/index.php?meta=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The subpattern `([^w-]+)` captures the part of the URL-path after `/blog/` and stores this in the `$1` backreference, which is used later as the `meta` URL parameter value in the *substitution* string (2nd argument). The regex character class `[^w-]` matches characters in the range `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_` (underscore) and `-` (hyphen), which covers your example.

The `QSA` flag will also append any query string that was on the initial request. If you are not expecting a query string on the initial request then you should remove this flag.

To clarify, you still need to actually change the URL in your HTML source to the canonical/friendly URL. ie. `/blog/How-We-Build-Your-Website`.

Note that if you have other directives in `.htaccess` then the order can be important.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the only way to do this would be by redirecting it in PHP.

You can do this by editing the post.php file, and putting this at the **top** of the file:

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['meta'])) { header("Location: ../".$_GET['meta']); exit; } ?>
```

This redirects to to the page without loading any other page data. If there is no "?meta=..." though, it will not redirect, it will instead load the rest of the page.

Comment: You can't do this in PHP. (The question is/was incorrectly tagged.)

Comment: this results in a 404 error I am loading data from the database using the meta in the URL your solution only makes the URL human readable but breaks the content, is there any other way to make the url cleaner and display the data ?

Comment: Try @MrWhite 's answer.